# Pass parallel variable "{}" as awk variable

Tags: bash, awk, gnu-parallel

I want to extract in the same order all lines in `ids.ped` according to a list of words (second column of `list_of_words`) preserving the same order.

**ids.ped file**:

```
2425 NA19901 0
2472 NA20291 0
2476 NA20298 0
1328 NA06989 0
...
```

I want to use `awk` and `parallel` for this task.

I tried the following:

```
cut -f2 list_of_words |
    parallel -j35 --keep-order \
    awk -v id={} 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{if($2 == id){print $2,$3}}' ids.ped
```

However, I get the error

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `awk -v id= BEGIN{FS=" "}{if($2 == id){print $2,$3}} ids.ped'
```

It seems I cannot pass `{}` this way.

Notes:

- `ids.ped` is big, that's way I want to parallelize
- I want to use `awk` since I want to extract lines according to second 
  column in `ids.ped`

For some reason I do not understand why `grep -w` extracts some lines twice, that is one reason I would rather use `awk`.

Any other answer to solve this problem efficiently is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: In the man page you can find the text: syntax error near unexpected token. The solution in the man page is -q,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your parameter passing problem (do you have empty columns at the beginning of the file?) but I did get the syntax error due to how `parallel` its interprets arguments.

```
/opt/local/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/opt/local/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `awk -v id=NA20291 BEGIN{FS=" "}{if($2 == id){print $2,$3}} foo.txt'
```

You've got three choices to fix the problem; you can add the `-q` option to `parallel` to ["protect against evaluation by the subshell"](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#QUOTING):

```
cut -f2 list_of_words |
    parallel -j35 -q --keep-order \
    awk -v id="{}" 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{if($2 == id){print $2,$3}}' ids.ped
```

You can move the `awk` code to a separate file; the rest of the command is simple enough that it doesn't need to be escaped:

```
cut -f2 list_of_words |
    parallel -j35 --keep-order awk -v id={} -f foo.awk ids.ped
```

Contents of `foo.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    FS=" "
}

{
    if($2 == id){
        print $2,$3
    }
}
```

Or, you can figure out how to escape the command. The manual linked above says "most people will never need more quoting than putting '\' in front of the special characters."

```
cut -f2 list_of_words |
    parallel -j35 --keep-order \
    awk -v id="{}" \''BEGIN{FS=" "}{if($2 == id){print $2,$3}}'\' ids.ped
```

Comment: Thanks @miken32! This is good for me. However, I don't understand the behavior of the code in `awk` and how it changes as a one-liner or a code file in the context of  `parallel`.

Comment: By the way, I don't have empty columns in neither file.

Comment: Check my update to the question; I found an option that will make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

As @miken32 said, providing the awk script as a parameter to parallel can be tricky, but here is one way to do it:

```
parallel -j1 --keep-order \
  awk -v id="{}" "'"'{ if ($2 == id ) { print $2,$3 }}'"'" ids.ped
```

The original question didn't provide an example of `list_of_words`, but here is a script illustrating the use of `parallel` with `awk`:

```
$ cat check
#!/bin/bash

function DATA {
cat<<EOF
1328    NA06989
2425    NA19901
EOF
    }


DATA | cut -f2 |
    parallel -j2 --keep-order awk -v id="{}" "'"'{ if ($2 == id ) { print $2,$3 }}'"'" ids.ped

$ ./check
NA06989 0
NA19901 0


$ parallel --version
GNU parallel 20160122
```

[This has been tested on a Mac with /usr/bin/awk, gawk, and mawk.]

Comment: I've provided a typescript showing it works on a Mac with various awks.  Could you be more specific about what OS, awk and parallel you are using?